# Spring Data Rest - Change the entity property used in item resource url

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I'm pretty new to Spring Data Rest and Spring in general.
I use Spring Data Rest with Spring Data Jpa and a Mysql DataBase.

I can't find how to change the Entity property used as Id in the URL.
Here basically what i'm trying to achieve:

I have the following entity: `Plant(id,code,name,...)`

Actually i obtain a plant item resource using

```
GET /plants/:id
```

I would like to access to this resource item using:

```
GET /plants/:code
```

`Plant.code` property is not the official `id` of the entity but is unique and makes much more sense to the final user of the API.

I have searched through the documentation and Google/SO but have not found any relevant answer.

So excuse me if the anwser is obvious

Comment: I'd argue what constitutes the URI shouldn't matter in a REST service as by definition the URI is opaque to a user. All that the client should care about is the link relation.

Comment: I understand that the argument fits the HATEOAS principle and i'm pretty new with this concept. My issue is really about ease of learning of the developers  who will use the API and because it fits really better the domain of the application because nobody knows and cares about the value of the ID which is a surrogate key. [Github official API GET repos url](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) is a good example of this: Although repositories have an id, their name is used in the url

Answer (score 1):

You could add a search endpoint like this, which returns a single matching resource:

```
GET /plants/search/findByCode?code=:code
```

You would do this by adding this to your repository interface:

```
Plant findByCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

Comment: This works but I don't think using query strings to retrieve a resource is really clean. Thanks for answer

Comment: In fact i need to follow the spec of the project i'm working on and adapt the tool. If it is not possible using Spring Data Rest i'll go the "manual" way using @RestController.